# Integrating FlatFileItemReaderBuilder with a specific API for reading files

Tags: java, spring-batch

In order to achieve my final year project i wrote a Java/spring program that reads all certificate files found in a given directory (public and private certifictes) using java.security.KeyStore and the X509Certificate  API ...., for each certificate file i created a Certificate java objet and i insert it in the data base. Now they told me that i should use Spring batch to execute the written code so after reading about it i found that the best way to do it is to use the **FlatFileItemReaderBuilder**, but the problem is that i didn't understand how to integrate it with the specific reading certificates API listed above.

Here's the written code:

```
private final  CertificatRepository CertificatRepository;

public CertificatService(CertificatRepository certificatRepository) {
    super();
    this.CertificatRepository = certificatRepository;
} 


public void save(Certificat certificat) {
    CertificatRepository.save(certificat);
}

public void saveAll(String chemin) {
    List <Certificat> certificats = parseCertificateDirectory(chemin);
    for (Certificat certificat : certificats) {
        save(certificat);
    }   
}

public List<Certificat> findAll() {
    return this.CertificatRepository.findAll();
}


public List<Certificat> listCertificates(String chemin) {
    return parseCertificateDirectory(chemin);

}


public Certificat findOne (String id) {
    return this.CertificatRepository.findOne(id);
}

private Certificat retrieveCertificate(String chemin, String name) {
    FileInputStream fils;
    Certificat certificat = null;
    try {
        fils = new FileInputStream(chemin + name);

        String extensionCertificat = name.substring(name.indexOf(".") + 1, name.length());
        if ("cer".equals(extensionCertificat)) {
            certificat = createCertificate(CertificateType.PUBLIC, (X509Certificate) getPublicCertificate(fils));
        }
        else {
            if ("p12".equals(extensionCertificat)) {
            certificat = createCertificate(CertificateType.PRIVATE, (X509Certificate) getPrivateCertificate(fils));
           }  
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return certificat;
}




//Creer un objet de type Certificat
private Certificat createCertificate(CertificateType typeCle, Certificate cert) {
    Certificat certificat;
    X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) cert;
    certificat = new Certificat();
    certificat.setDn(x509Certificate.getIssuerDN().toString());
    certificat.setCn(x509Certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().toString());
    certificat.setSatrtdate(x509Certificate.getNotBefore());
    certificat.setEnddate(x509Certificate.getNotAfter());
    certificat.setCle_public("");
    certificat.setCle_prive("");
    certificat.setPublicPrive(typeCle.toString());
    certificat.setType("V"+x509Certificate.getVersion());
    return certificat;
}

//Retourne un certificat publique
private Certificate getPublicCertificate(FileInputStream fils) {
    CertificateFactory cf;
    Certificate  certificate = null;
    try {
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        certificate = cf.generateCertificate(fils);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return certificate;
}

// Retourne un certificat prive
private X509Certificate getPrivateCertificate(FileInputStream fils) {
    KeyStore p12;
    X509Certificate x509Certificate = null;
    try {
        p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        p12.load(fils, "password".toCharArray());
        x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) p12.getCertificate("1");
    } 

    catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    catch (CertificateException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return x509Certificate;
}

// parcours le chemin qui contient tous les certificats
public List <Certificat> parseCertificateDirectory (String chemin) {
    System.out.println("chemin : " + chemin);
    List <Certificat> certifs = new ArrayList<>();
    File folder = new File(chemin);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File file : listOfFiles) {

        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            certifs.add(retrieveCertificate(chemin, file.getName()));
        }


    }
    return certifs;
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pls share your code ... or github link

Comment: @NghiaDo i added the written code and it works now. The problem is i didn't understand how to integrate it to spring batch :(

Answer (score 3):

In your case, items are files (of type `File`) and not lines within flat files. So the `FlatFileItemReader` is not the appropriate reader for your requirement.

For the reader, you can use the `IteratorItemReader` and pass the list of files (result of `parseCertificateDirectory` method) at construction time.

For the writer, you can use the `ItemWriterAdapter` to adapt your `CertificatRepository` and use it as a writer (with the `save` method as `targetMethod`).

Now that you have your reader and writer, you can take a look at one of the samples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples to see how to configure a Spring Batch job with a chunk-oriented step.

Comment: Many thanks ;) you really saved my day i'lll work on it. Amira